# receive DatagramPacket

Tags: java, udp, datagram

In `DatagramPacket` class all constructors require an int parameter as "length".
Why do I need to set the length of a `DatagramPacket` when I try to receive it, since I do not necessarily know how long the packet is?
And which number should I set it to?

edit:
Let me change my question to this:

if `DatagramSocket.receive` method has signature

```
public DatagramPacket receive() {};
```

instead of

```
public void receive(Datagrampacket p) {};
```

wouldn't it make more sense? since like said, the receiver usually does not know what the packet looks like.

Since the delivery service analogy is often applied to UDP, let's say:

DatagramSocket is like a mailbox. DatagramPacket is like the parcel envelope. DatagramPacket.data is the content inside envelope. For delivery service the receiver provides mailbox but not the envelope.

Comment: Your edit is misleading. The example replaces the question "why do we need to duplicate the datagram.buffer.length with datagram.length in the Datagrampacket?" with why do we need to supply the buffer in the first place. These are two different questions. And, it is not clear what you are asking now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're asking it to write into a byte array which you're *also* providing. So make sure your byte array is as large as the largest packet you would expect to handle, and pass in the length of the array for the `length` parameter.

EDIT: For the edited question, that API would mean the receiving code had to create a new buffer each time. With the existing API, the same byte array can be used for multiple calls, because the caller gets to decide when they've finished using it.

Now admittedly it would make sense to have an overload like this:

```
public DatagramPacket(byte[] buffer)
{
    this(buffer, buffer.length);
}
```

... but that's a different matter.

Comment: That is the question actually. Why should you supply the array with its length in java program? Is it Occam's KISS principle?

Comment: @Val: It allows you to reuse the same buffer for all reads, which is more efficient than the receiving code creating a new byte array each time. It probably also mimics the native interface, of course...

Comment: No. Buffer is reused when you supply it over and over again. Supplying length does not make it more reusable.

Comment: @Val: You misunderstand me. What's the alternative to the client providing the buffer? The packet could create its own - but then it can't reuse it. If the client provides the buffer it *can* be reused. Now yes, there could easily be an overload which just delegates by using the `length` property, but it makes sense to at least be able to limit the length (and offset) which is written to.